# Is there a daily limit for tag scores

Tags: discussion, tag-badges, tag-score

For reputation points there is a daily limit of 200, which mean when one got 20 upvotes, times 10 equal 200, one can't gain more rep. points that same day.

At the same time those 20 upvotes adds to the "tag" score, and based on someone's tag score one is awarded badges at 100, 400 and 1000.

So if one get 30 upvotes in one day, will also the tag score be limited to only 20 scores, and if so, 20 scores per tag, or in total?

---

Updated

I just found this post, [maximum daily reputation and top users score [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218096/maximum-daily-reputation-and-top-users-score), and it appears to be a duplicate, and if it is, and still apply, please close this as such, or let me know and I delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no daily limit on tag scores. The entirety of the 30 answer score will be credited to the relevant tags, and it will even be reflected in the tag leaderboards.